# Is PuTTY required on target SSH machine?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

This may seem like a silly question, and I *think* already know the answer, but I haven't been able to confirm it yet.

When using PuTTY to establish an SSH connection to another machine, does the target machine have to have PuTTY installed on it too?

My assumption is that the SSH connection is independent of PuTTY, as PuTTY is just the utility that is being used to establish that kind of connection, and thus it is not required to be installed on the target machine.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

PuTTY doesn't have to be installed on the remote machine, but *something* does. As a comparison, your web browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc) is an HTTP client which talks to an HTTP server (Apache, Nginx, etc) on Stack Overflow's server. In the same way, PuTTY is an SSH client on your Windows machine which talks to an SSH server somewhere else.

If you're connecting to a Linux/Unix based system, you don't really have to think about that, because the SSH server software is installed and set up by default, but if it wasn't there, there's nothing PuTTY can talk to. If the remote computer is running Windows, it is unlikely to have an SSH server running on it unless somebody has specifically set something up - although I read somewhere that the PowerShell team are working on adding one.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation; it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Putty is not required on the target machine.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; PuTTY is to SSH as FileZilla is to FTP: just a utility.

The target machine doesn't need PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

As you think : Putty is just a tool. If you want to use SSH just check that the target has SSH enabled.